# How to connect Cassandra in Jupyter notebook In Anaconda with Python?

Tags: python, cassandra, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use Cassandra on my computer. What I have done:

```
! pip install cassandra-driver
```

Successfully installed cassandra-driver-3.24.0 geomet-0.2.1.post1

```
import Cassandra
```

Create a connection to the database

Then the connection to the database

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
try: 
    cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1']) 
    session = cluster.connect()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

There is an error:

```
('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1:9042': ConnectionRefusedError(10061, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it")})
```

I am wondering whether there is a configuration problem, then I check below:
The user variable for Java_Hone as below:
[image]

Cassandra is installed here:
C:\Users\xx\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages
There are two packages under site-packages:
[image]

I have checked a lot of answers, but couldn't find the solution. I am not familiar with the configuration. Can anybody help with it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've responded to this same question you posted on [community.datastax.com](https://community.datastax.com).

You're connecting to the cluster on `localhost` and it's not running there so the connection fails. You need to specify one of the IPs of the nodes in the cluster.

For more info, see my answer to your post in https://community.datastax.com/questions/9162/. Cheers!

Comment: Dear Erick, thank you for your answer. I might be a bit far from the step you mentioned, as  I then tried to run Cassandra in CMD, and it showed that 1. PowerShell   Set-ExecutionPolicy needs to be changed 2. could not create JVM. My Java version is 13, Cassandra version 3 might only support Java 8?

Comment: @Annie That is correct, Cassandra 3 will likely not run on Java 13.

Comment: Aaron is correct. Cassandra 3.x only works with Java 8. C* 4.0 will eventually support Java 11. Cheers!

Comment: Apache Release Note says Cassandra 3.11 is supported on Java >= 1.8 See 'Requirements' in https://github.com/apache/cassandra/tree/cassandra-3.11.  I run it on Java 11 just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've released a Jupyter kernel for Cassandra CQL.  See [cqljupter](https://github.com/bschoening/cqljupyter).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it:

```
! pip install cassandra-driver
```

Then connect to your local host and the required space

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

cluster = Cluster()

session = cluster.connect('keyspace')
```